# Further to refer to time

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, grammaticality, american-english, time

May I use *further* to refer to time? For instance: *I'll do it further*

Thank you

Comment: Not without qualifying it as being a time reference, e.g. "I'll do it further in the future".  But even that sounds odd.  Normally you would say "I'll do it later."

Comment: No, your example isn't idiomatic. The nearest I can get to "using **further** to refer to time" would something like [*(the wine) is aged further during the second fermentation*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22aged+further+during%22) (***further** = for additional time*). But essentially, ***further / farther*** is a *spatial* reference that's not normally used "temporally". In my own example it simply means ***more*** (figuratively, ***at a greater distance*** along some real or figurative 2-dimensional line).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *further* for time, but not in that sentence. The word *further* is a comparative, so it means *more distant than something else*, or *later than something else*. Your sentence only refers to one time in the future, so you can't use *further*. (Strangely, *later* is a comparative which doesn't suffer from this restriction.)

So, for example, you cannot say:

> Further down that road is a meadow with a zebra in it;

you would need to say

> Down that road is a meadow with a zebra in it.

But you could say:

> If you go down that road a mile or two, you'll see a beautiful lake, and further down you'll find a meadow with a zebra in it.

And in reference to time, you could say:

> We will have the apps for doctors up tomorrow, but the ones for patients will only come online further on.